# eigenvalues for an Infinte sum of Diagnolizable matrix

Tags: matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that A is a diagonalizable matrix. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{j=0}^n (A^j)$exists if the absolute values of all the eigenvalues of A are smaller than one.
Can someone please give me a hint?
I feel that  A is diagonalizable and all of its eigenvalues lie in the half-open interval $(−1,1]$, and a necessary condition is that the eigenvalues of A are either equal to 1 or strictly less than 1 in absolute value.
However, I don't know how to prove

Answer (score 0):

If A is diagonizable, it means that there exists an invertable $P$ and a diagonal $D$ matrix s.t.
$$A = PDP^{-1}$$
Then you can prove this by using
$$A^j = (PDP^{-1})^j = PD^jP^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! just to reconfirm. I can now say that since D is a diagonal matrix comprising of eigenvalues of A, thus the absolute value of eigenvalues must be smaller than 1 for the above to exist.

Comment: Yest, but keep in mind that the original exercise is the sum of these. Which in this case means that you have a geometric series in each element of the diagonal.